# How can I link MongoDB when I use the class in next.js?

Tags: reactjs, mongodb, next.js

There was a problem using Next.js + MongoDB. It worked well when using only functions, but it doesn't work when using class. Errors include:

Server Error

> ReferenceError: pets is not defined

This error happened while generating the page. Any console logs will be displayed in the terminal window.

```
loader={<h4>Loading...</h4>}

{pets.map((pet) => (
     ^
      <div className="cardPersnal">
         <div className="row">
            <div className="cardMain card">
```

MongoDB interlocking part code is as follows.

```
export async function getServerSideProps() {
    await dbConnect()
  
    /* find all the data in our database */
    const result = await Pet.find({})
    const pets = result.map((doc) => {
      const pet = doc.toObject()
      pet._id = pet._id.toString()
      return pet
    })
  
    return { props: { pets: pets } }
  }
```

After class declaration, the following structure was created:

```
import dbConnect from '../utils/dbConnect'
import Pet from '../models/Pet'
import React from "react";


class App extends React.Component {
...
        {pets.map((pet) => (
    ...
    )
...
}

export async function getServerSideProps() {
    await dbConnect()
  
    /* find all the data in our database */
    const result = await Pet.find({})
    const pets = result.map((doc) => {
      const pet = doc.toObject()
      pet._id = pet._id.toString()
      return pet
    })
  
    return { props: { pets: pets } }
  }
```

How do I get MongoDB data from inside the class?

Comment: Did you mean to use `this.props.pets`?

Comment: Oh, let's try again by specifying props. Thank you.